# Best practices for where to record data when using Gatsby, and how to import that data into gatsby.config.js or graphql

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I followed along with the [Gatsby Docs about data in Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-four/) where they showed me how I could create a graphql variable in the siteMetadata block within

**gatsby.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Title from siteMetadata`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-emotion`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typography`,
      options: {
        pathToConfigModule: `src/utils/typography`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

and then could access it using a graphql query

```js
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"

export default ({ data }) => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>About {data.site.siteMetadata.title}</h1>
    <p>
      We're the only site running on your computer dedicated to showing the best
      photos and videos of pandas eating lots of food.
    </p>
  </Layout>
)

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

---

I am wanting to keep all the data from my web app separate from the rest of the code, and all contained in one place, for example I might have a file that looks like

```
navLinks = ["Home", "About", "Contact"]
homePageIntro = "Hello! Thank you for visiting my website"
logo = 'https://aws.amazon.com/mys3.logo'
contactPhoto = 'https://aws.amazon.com/mys3.logo'
aboutPageFirstPar = 'This is the first paragraph on the about page'
aboutPageSecondPar = 'This is the Second paragraph on the about page'
```

or maybe it might be better practice to separate my text and links into separate files?

I just have this feeling that inserting all data variables into siteMetadata might not be the best way to go about this, but maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your data in a single JSON file and then use `gatsby-transformer-json` to put it to graphql. That way, you can access your data using a graphql query.

PS. You can also use the `useStaticQuery` hook.

Read more about it here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-json/